# How can we know that a random satellite image is atmospherically corrected or not using python?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, landsat, satellite, atmospheric-correction, change-detection

If a satellite image in .tiff format was given. what are the values that can be obtained from a satellite image using python to see whether it has atmospheric errors or not?

I am expecting what values are required and libraries in python to extract those values

PS: I know that Landsat level 2 is atmospherically corrected but, I want to know to know random satellite .tiff image which is given as input is atmospherically corrected or not.